# How to edit a node programatically after it has been created?

Tags: 7, views, nodes

My articles have a field 'Ranking' and I'd like to give a value to this field after a node has been created. The value depends on the node's ranking in a view called 'Top 3'. I tried the following in my custom module 'Top', but it doesn't work.

```
function top_node_insert($node) {
  $top = views_get_view_result('top_3');

  $found = false;  
  foreach($top as $key => $value) {
    if ($value->nid == $node->nid) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
  }

  if ($found) $ranking = $key + 1;
  $node->field_hoogste_ranking[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $ranking;
}
```

What did I do wrong and what's the correct version?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no `hook_node_save`. If you wish to do something after a node has been created, use `hook_node_insert`.

Comment: @AjitS: I've tried the same code with `hook_node_insert`, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the Node API Hooks description [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/group/node_api_hooks/7), you will see that hook_node_insert is called after field_attach_insert. That means that at the point hook_node_insert is called the fields for the node are already written to the database. If you keep your code in top_node_insert, then add field_attach_update('node', $node) to update the fields with the new data. It might look something like this:

```
function top_node_insert($node) {
  $top = views_get_view_result('top_3');

  $found = false;  
  foreach($top as $key => $value) {
    if ($value->nid == $node->nid) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
  }

  if ($found) {
    $ranking = $key + 1;
    $node->field_hoogste_ranking[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $ranking;
    field_attach_update('node', $node);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can try and use hook_node_presave.

Comment: $value->nid == $node->nid should be wrong as node has yet not been written into the DB and the View couldn't have got the nid using node_load.

Comment: @AgA: It does work, because `hook_node_insert` is activated after the node has been saved to the database.

Comment: There's only a `;` missing at the end of the last code line. Perhaps you can  change it for future users.

Comment: No problem. I'm the one who should thank you. It's works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use hook_node_presave()

if you use hook_node_insert() then the value will not be saved in $node object

Comment: hook_node_presave() is invoked before node is actually created while hook_node_insert() is invoked after nodes get created, so you will find nid in case of hook_node_insert() but in case of hook_node_presave().

Comment: Yes.. you are right .. I wrote that by mistake .. Yesterday I faced the problem if hook_node_insert.. which is not saving field value associated with $node object... while node_presave solved my problem..

Note: I have updated my answer.. thanks